# Can I print my React-Native JSX component in expo using a Printer

Tags: html, reactjs, react-native, dynamic-programming

In Expo you can use the print API to print out html or convert it into pdf. In my case I have a receipt component that I would like to print and it has dynamically rendered data in it. Is there a way I can convert this jsx component directly into html?